# Session gets unset in else while the if statement is true Joomla 3 onAfterInitialise()

Tags: php, session-variables, unset, joomla3.4

in the onAfterInitialise function of Joomla i get the current link which i explode to see the alias of the menu item.
If the statement is true i print a name, which gets printed.
In the else statement i unset a session variable, which also gets unset.
So the if statement is true but still the session variable gets unset.
This only occurs when i go to the next page of my list by pagination.

```
$link = explode("/", str_replace(".html", "", $_SERVER["REQUEST_URI"]));
print_r($link);

if ("producten" == $link[1]){
    print_r("working");     
}else{
     unset($_SESSION["searchfield"]);
}
```

Result = "working", but when i print the session variable its empty now. Any idea what i'm doing wrong?

Comment: make sure you're calling this part of code only once ?

Comment: It happens in the method onAfterInitialise which is triggered automatically after the initialise of the application is called(https://docs.joomla.org/Plugin/Events/System)

Comment: found out it is triggered twice when i click on the pagination, no idea why this happens though